# Recommended solution to get AngularJS to recognize invalid input already detected by the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, validation

I have an issue (in Chrome) where a number input is determined to be invalid by the browser, but valid according to Angular.

```
<form name="form_name">
    <input type="number" step="any" id="a_number" name="a_number" min="0"
        ng:model="aNumber"/>
    <button type="button" ng:disabled="form_name.$invalid">Label</button>
</form>
```

1. If I enter `5`, it passes both Angular's and the browser's validation leaving the button enabled.
2. If I enter `-5`, it fails both Angular's and the browser's validation disabling the button.
3. However, if I enter something like `-` or `5.a`, it fails the browser's validation allowing me to indicate and error, but does not fail Angular's validation leaving the button enabled!

[Run it on JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/MarkMYoung/LFa3E/)

I think Angular's validation is never called because the browser is not firing any other events after it detects an error.  There is an `invalid` event, but it's only emitted on form submission or after `checkValidity()` is called.  If I change the input to a text input and add a `pattern` for floating point numbers, Angular is able to receive the proper events and determine validation has failed; however, I must leave the input type as number to assist phone softkeys (and that work-around would completely ignore the bigger problem of Angular not detecting form errors).

So, should I have a directive:

1. Attach a listener for an event like `keyup` which manually calls `checkValidity()`,
2. Attach a listener for `invalid` to manually set Angular's validity, and
3. Attach an internal listener for `change` to manually clear Angular's validity?

What's your solution?

Comment: One observation is that if you add `required` to the input, everything seems to work as expected.

Comment: Thank you, Davin.  I will use that reasonable work-around on my required inputs; however, many of them are not required.  I am really hoping I can leave non-required inputs blank so their values will be null.

Comment: If they are not required but you still want to validate, you could use an extra `ng-pattern`.

Comment: :-) Yes, I omitted that from my question to avoid confusion or distraction.  What's sad is that Anoj's `novalidate` suggestion doesn't work even with `ng-pattern`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can remove the browser validation  and use the angular validation

```
<form action="" novalidate>
```

novalidate will help you to remove the browser validation

Comment: I tried that in the JSFiddle to which I linked and it doesn't work.  Your idea leads me to believe it's solely an Angular bug.